# Fetch PHAssets that don't belong to any PHAssetCollection

Tags: ios, phasset

Is it possible to fetch all `PHAsset`s that don't belong to any `PHAssetColletion`? Basically what I want to achieve is to get all photos that are not sorted to any album.

I know I can do this:

```
let photos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHFetchOptions())
var photosWithoutAlbum: [PHAsset] = []
photos.enumerateObjects({
    asset, index, stop in
    let albums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsContaining(asset, with: .album, options: PHFetchOptions())
    if albums.count == 0 {
        photosWithoutAlbum.append(asset)
    }
})
```

But maybe there is a better/faster way using `PHFetchOptions` or different fetch method?